# hide and show asp.net radio button via css and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

So I'm trying to hide and show some content based on a selection of a listbox. I'm hiding some content using css when the page loads and then displaying it when Certain things are selected. Most of it works, but can't figure out why these radio buttons won't display.

Here are the radio buttons and a label...

```
        <br /><!--View/Send By-->
        <asp:Label ID="lblViewSend" runat="server" Text="View/Send as" style="display:none;"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdViewPrint" Text="View/Print" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:disableFields();" GroupName="viewSend" Checked="True" style="display:none; margin-left:10px;" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdEmail" Text="Email" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:emailFields();" GroupName="viewSend" style="display:none; margin-left:10px;" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdFax" Text="Fax" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:faxFields();" GroupName="viewSend" style="display:none; margin-left:10px;" />
```

The javascript to display them when an item is selected in the listbox...

```
function lbSelected() {
             var sel = document.getElementById('<%=lbPatientVisits.ClientID%>');
             var listlength = sel.options.length;

             document.getElementById('<%=lblViewSend.ClientID%>').style.display = "inherit";
             document.getElementById('<%=rdViewPrint.ClientID%>').style.display = "inherit";
             document.getElementById('<%=rdEmail.ClientID%>').style.display = "inherit";
             document.getElementById('<%=rdFax.ClientID%>').style.display = "inherit";
//...plus more code that functions correctly...
    }
```

The label will appear on the page when it's supposed to, but the radio buttons will not. I also tried this as a little variation and it didn't work this way either...

```
var rbtn = document.getElementById('<%=rdViewPrint.ClientID%>');
         rbtn.style.display = 'inherit';
```

What am I missing or overlooking? The code seems to work fine for regular buttons and labels, but not radio boxes?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does a basic $("#yourId").hide() / $("#yourId").show() not work for you ?

Comment: I don't think he is using jQuery.

Comment: Hanlet is correct, not using jQuery.

Comment: Give it a try setting `RepeatLayout="Flow"` for radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is a full example using jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#name").click(function () {
            $("#<%=this.myRadio.ClientID %>").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>


    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="myRadio">
        <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <input type="button" id="name" value="click me" />
```

Comment: I'm not currently, nor interested in adding in jQuery at this point in time.